# How to change style of the tab bar in Eclipse look like this?

Tags: eclipse

Anybody know how to change the tab bar like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version, you will find that at `Window > Preferences > General > Appearance > Show traditional style tabs`.

[image]

Comment: This option was removed from Eclipse in 2012. See [Eclipse Bug 367691](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=367691).

Comment: As you may have read ("Depending on the version"), old versions are old versions, and sometimes, something changes. But for all people using those old versions, that answer is valid.

Comment: I wasn't questioning the validity of the answer, just adding an additional reference in case anyone was looking for this option in newer versions. I'm hoping that if enough attention gets drawn to that bug, the option might be reintroduced into Eclipse.

Answer (score 10):

Eclipse Juno and later do not have this checkbox anymore.

To enable traditional style tabs:

1. Go to `[eclipse_folder]\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.2.1.v201209141800\css`
2. Open the css file that corresponds to your selected theme, e.g. e4_default_win7.css
3. Then find the selector **.MPartStack** and set **swt-simple** to **true**

Comment: For me using Luna and the Windows Classic theme it was `org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.0.1.v20141126-1957\e4_classic_win7.css`

Answer (score 2):

For Eclipse Mars on Windows with the default theme ("Classic"):

Edit:

`C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.1.0.v20150511-0913\css\e4_classic_winxp.css`

change:

```
.MPartStack {
    swt-simple: false;
}
```

to:

```
.MPartStack {
    swt-simple: true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Jeeeyul's Chrome Theme](https://github.com/jeeeyul/eclipse-themes) and configure the color and tab-round by your own choice.

Answer (score 0):

2021-09 uses a flat tab and a nice looking close icon.

[image: Screenshot]