# How to change Eclipse declining tool windows headers

Tags: eclipse

I am not sure if I described my problem well in the title of this post but please feel to change it to something more meaningful if you have better naming for it. But my problem is that, I really don't like how Eclipse tool window headers containers' borders look like:

[image]

It has a slowly declining border. I want it to be vertical border. I tried several themes but didn't like them as well.

Can somone please tell me how to change them to vertical line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Eclipse Luna and it doesn't "Show traditional style tabs" any more. And later I have found this topic [How to change style of the tab bar in Eclipse look like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937925/how-to-change-style-of-the-tab-bar-in-eclipse-look-like-this) but the location it says has changed. This is what I did to change for Eclipse Luna on Mac.

1. Go to **Macintosh HD ▸ Applications ▸ eclipse ▸ plugins ▸ org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.0.1.v20140819-1717 ▸ css**
2. Open **e4_default_mac.css** file. This file will differ based on the theme you selected.
3. Find the following code and change `swt-simple`to `true`.

Code that you need will be similar to the following:

```
.MPartStack {
   swt-simple: true;
   swt-mru-visible: false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preferences -> General -> Appearance and select "Show Traditional Style tabs".

See this:

[image]

Comment: I had to find another solution. Yours are not visible anymore.